# Howto convert Expression Func<T, object[]> to Func<T, object>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of fields that need to be selected in a linq query.
The fields has the format `Expression<Func<T, object[]>>`. (array of fields)
(I can't change this, the order of fields is important for other code)

I need to convert this to a selector that I can use in an `IQueryable<T>`.
But how can I do that? How can I implement the GetSelector() function?

```
var fields = GetFields<Employee>(e => new[] { e.Name, e.Street });
var selector = GetSelector(fields);
var result = await qry.Select(selector).ToListAsync();
```

GetFields function:

```
private Expression<Func<T, object[]>> GetFields<T>(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> fields)
{
    return fields;
}
```

GetSelector function:

```
private Expression<Func<T, object>> GetSelector<T>(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> fields)
{
    //How to convert? 
    //It should return somehting like this: (e => new {e.Name, e.Street})
}
```

Comment: AFAIK you cannot really get any informations from a delegate (like accessed parameters / members / etc), you need an expression tree for that. You cannot get the name of fields (i.e. `e.Name` and `e.Street`) from the delegate directly. You could try to execute the delegate, and then use reflection to analyze the type of object returned (i.e. the anonymous type), but that sounds more like a workaround (and is probably prone to errors)... So I guess you'll either need to change the signature of `GetFields()` to use expressions instead of delegates, or find an entirely different solution...

Comment: I already changed it to expression while you typed your comment. Sorry.

Comment: Can you explain your planned usage with a some more details? I can't really wrap my head around what you want to do once you have such a selector expression...

Comment: @r03 this feels like re-inventing the wheel. Why not have the an expression that returns an anonymous object which would encapsulate both the field names and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about the `IQueryable` part (please test it), but changing the expression signature is quite easy, since `object[]` is an `object`

```
private static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetSelector<T>(Expression<Func<T, object[]>> fields)
{
    var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(fields.Body, fields.Parameters);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I seems to work... I did't expected that it could be that simple. I have to read more about expression trees.